# Is it posibble to use two shipping method together in magento?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping

I have a scenario where a customer placed an order which have 5 items. Now i want to apply two shipping method such that first shipping method applies on two product and second shipping method applies on other three products.

My idea to do :
I have made an attribute in edit product section when we select it yes that product should use the first shipping method all other products should use the default shipping method even if the order is same.

Is it possible to do , and any one have any idea please share it.

Thanks,
Sarvagya

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the multi address shipping option, this way you can use different shipping options (you get one payment and it generates multiple orders for each shipment).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do many changes bc everywhere in sales (quote, order) shipping method stored and used as string. May be better to do several orders, each order for each shipping method. You will be able to use same approches like multi address shipping use. Your quote will have two shipping addresses with different shipping methods, items but with same address.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is it possible to specify shipping method at product level

Comment: sorry but nope. i saw extension which adds shipping restrictions for each product, for example some products could be shipped only by ground, but still order should be shipped by one method.